# Integral is equal to $0$

Tags: integration, fourier-analysis, trigonometric-series

> Let be $f \in L^1[0,1]$, then it applies $ \int_0^1 \exp(2i\pi xk)f(x n)\,dx=0$ for $n,k\in \mathbb{N}$ with $0<k<n$.

Ideas: f can be extended to a function on $\mathbb{R}$ with period $1$, hence $f$ can be approximated by a trigonometric polynomial with respect to $L^1$-Norm $\|\|_1$. Since it applies $\|f\|_1:=\int_0^1 |f| d\lambda$ and $|\exp(2i\pi xk)f(x)|=|f(x)|$ for any$f\in L^1[0,1]$, we have  $\|f\|_1=\|\ g\cdot f\|_1$, where $g(x):=\exp(2i\pi xk)$. In my opinion it seems that $L^1$-Norm $\|\|_1$ is too "coarse" for being helpful in that proof, but I see no other way.

Thanks for the help

bests

bjn

edit: Sorry for the messed up post, I hope now is all okay.

Comment: What is $a$?  It doesn't tell us anything about how $f$ is defined outside $[0,1]$. So how can we deal with $f(xn)$ if $n > 1/x$?

Comment: What is the conclusion of your desired statement? I see an integral, but not what it's supposed to be equal to.

Comment: I edited my intial post. I hope now it's more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I read between the lines of your question:

1. $a$ means $k$.
2. $f$ is extended to $\mathbb R$ as a periodic function with period $1$. (Alternatively, replace $nx$ with the fractional part of $nx$ as the argument of $f$.)

With the above additions, it is true that 
$$
\int_0^1 \exp(2i\pi xk) f(x n)\,dx =0 ,\quad 0<k<n
$$
The reason is that  each value of $f$ is repeated $n$ times (periodicity), each time being multiplied by values of the exponential function that add up to $0$. To make this formal, split the integral into $n$ parts and do some substitution: 
$$
\begin{split}
\int_0^1 \exp(2i\pi xk) f(x n)\,dx & = \frac{1}{n} \int_0^n \exp(2i\pi t k/n) f(t)\,dt \\
& = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{j=0}^{n-1} 
\int_{j}^{j+1} \exp(2i\pi tk/n) f(t)\,dt \\ 
& =\frac{1}{n} \sum_{j=0}^{n-1}  \int_{0}^{1} \exp(2i\pi (t +j)k/n) f(t)\,dt  \\
& =\frac{1}{n} \sum_{j=0}^{n-1} \exp(2i \pi j k/n) \int_{0}^{1} \exp(2i\pi t k/n) f(t)\,dt
\end{split} $$
The punch line is that the integral does not involve $j$ anymore, and the exponentials sum up to zero (use the geometric sum formula).

---

Upon request, a proof using the density of trigonometric polynomials in $L^1$. For every $\epsilon>0$ there is a polynomial $$p(x) = \sum_{m=-M}^M \exp(2\pi i m x)$$ such that $\|p-f\|_{L^1}<\epsilon$. By the integral triangle inequality,
$$
\left|\int_0^1 \exp(2i\pi xk) f(x n)\,dx - \int_0^1 \exp(2i\pi xk) p(x n)\,dx\right| <\epsilon
$$
Direct computation shows that 
$$\int_0^1 \exp(2i\pi xk) p(x n)\,dx =0 
$$
(just plug in the sum and simplify: you get a bunch of exponentials, each of which integrates to zero.) Conclusion follows.

Comment: I understand your proof, although I think there are a typo: Shouldn't be in the last two lines $f(t)$ instead of $f(xn)$? 
But I don't see your motivation for the proof (how do you figure that out informally?), in particular what do you mean by "each value of f is repeated n times"? I only see that the argument of $f$ in the integral is repeated n times. 
Are you sure that there is no proof using the fact that f can be approximated by a trigonometric polynomial?

Comment: Can be $$
\left|\int_0^1 \exp(2i\pi xk) f(x n)\,dx - \int_0^1 \exp(2i\pi xk) p(x n)\,dx\right| <\epsilon
$$ deduce without the triange inequality?
By $$\left|\int_0^1 \exp(2i\pi xk) f(x n)\,dx - \int_0^1 \exp(2i\pi xk) p(x n)\,dx\right|< \int_0^1 \left|\exp(2i\pi xk) f(x n)\,dx -\exp(2i\pi xk) p(x n) \right|,dx = \int_0^1 \left| f(x n) -  p(x n) \right|dx=\int_0^1 \left| f(x) -  p(x) \right| = \|p-f\|_{L^1}<\epsilon$$

Comment: All right, thanks a lot.